# Azure Devops release pipeline - Get artifact variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've a Release pipeline in AzureDevops which pulls it's artifact from Azure Container Registry.

By creating a new release, at the "dockerbuild" needs to be selected which image from ACR shall be chosen: [image]

Currently i can't access the variable "dockerbuild" with it's value "1358 in the release pipeline. How do i need to write this, for access from powerShell?

I tried these approaches, without luck:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you checked my answer, does it work on your side? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article of [release artifact alias Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#general-artifact) that Charles provided is correct.

But the usage he provided still have problem.

It only works on OS like windows OS which is not case-sensitive.

See the below usage:

```
Write-Host "$ env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_dockerbuild_BUILDNUMBER"

Write-Host $env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_dockerbuild_BUILDNUMBER #This only works on windows.

Write-Host "$ env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DOCKERBUILD_BUILDNUMBER"

Write-Host $env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DOCKERBUILD_BUILDNUMBER #This will work both on windows and linux.

Write-Host "$ (Release.Artifacts.dockerbuild.BuildNumber)"

Write-Host $(Release.Artifacts.dockerbuild.BuildNumber) #In Inline script, this will always work.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following,

```
Write-Host $env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_dockerbuild_BUILDNUMBER
```

You probably already see the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#artifact-variables).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `$(Build.BuildNumber)`.